# Continue using subscription after exception

Tags: .net, exception, system.reactive, observer-pattern

I was trying out a "type-to-search" Reactive-Extensions sample which takes a string from a textbox (WPF app if it matters) and does a potentially-lengthy server-side search (simulated in my case with a Thread.Sleep) and displays the result(s) in a listbox.

The key features of this particular "module" would be :

- async search; UI is not frozen while searching
- throttled; typing fast would not generate a server-side search for each keystroke
- distinct searching; after searching for "asd" and having the result(s) displayed typing fast [backspace], d (i.e. deleting the last character and retyping it quick) would not redo the server-side search
- drop-intermediary-results; if I type "asd" and briefly wait (causing the server-side search to be launched) and then, BEFORE the results for asd are displayed finish the search string those intermediary/particular results are dropped

**the issue is that after a single exception from the heavy method (the one doing the 'server-side search') the subscription is terminated and cannot be used**

So far I only found out a workaround by resubscriping to the IObservable object but this feels wrong. I have also tried .Retry() but although I get to reuse the subscription my `OnError` handler does not get called anymore.

The code looks like this :

```
    private IObservable<object> _resultsFromTypeToSearch;

    private void SetupObserver()
    {
        var throttledUserInput =
            (from evt in Observable.FromEventPattern<TextChangedEventArgs>(TxtSearch, "TextChanged")
             select ((TextBox)evt.Sender).Text)
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.6)) // this ensures that only after 0.6 seconds the user input is taken into consideration
                .DistinctUntilChanged();             // this ensures only changed input is taken into consideration

        var getDataFunc = new Func<string, object>(GetExpensiveData);
        var searchAsync = Observable.FromAsyncPattern<string, object>(getDataFunc.BeginInvoke, getDataFunc.EndInvoke);

        var z = from text in throttledUserInput
                from word in searchAsync(text).TakeUntil(throttledUserInput)
                select word;  // TakeUntil will drop an ongoing search if a new search is requested in the meantime
        _resultsFromTypeToSearch = z.ObserveOn(TxtSearch); // this ensures that we'll get notified on the UI thread
        _resultsFromTypeToSearch.Subscribe(PresentResults, OnError);
    }

    private void OnError(Exception obj)
    {
        ClearUI();
        MessageBox.Show("Error");

        _resultsFromTypeToSearch.Subscribe(PresentResults, OnError); // THIS IS MY WORKAROUND WHICH FEELS BAD
    }

    private void ClearUI()
    {
        IsBusy = false;
        Results.Clear();
    }

    private void PresentResults(object result)
    {
        ClearUI();
        Results.Add(result.ToString());
    }

    private object GetExpensiveData(string searchString)
    {
        IsBusy = true;
        if (DateTime.Now.Millisecond % 3 == 0) throw new ServerException();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return "Data for " + searchString;
    }
```

**Any better way to do this?**

Comment: Why not catch the exception _before_ it reaches the subscription? My understanding is that this is part of the contract of the IObservable interface, after OnError is called nothing else will happen.

Comment: That is, catch the exception in the `GetExpensiveData` method? That is one, pretty good, approach!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was misunderstanding Rx. A sequence once it gets faulted it can not be reused. The simple solution is to recreate the subscription(s), i.e.: call again SetupObserver()

Answer (score 1):

The `Catch` operator helps here.

In your code, I think you could do this to prevent the subscription from ending when searchAsync fails:

```
var searchAsync = Observable
    .FromAsyncPattern<string, object>(getDataFunc.BeginInvoke, getDataFunc.EndInvoke)
    .Catch(e => Observable.Empty<object>()) // eat the error and return "no results" for this search.
```

You can return any new observable you want.  You could log the error and return another search attempt.  In this case I just return an empty observable which make the overall subscription behave as if that search attempt had never happened.

Comment: .. but what will happen AFTER the Catch(e=>...) lambda is effectively executed? Will the subscription work as before? As far as I understand the Observable supplied in the Catch extension is all there will be observed from that point on and the old one is discarded..

Comment: Right, but then as soon as the user types another character (which causes `throttledUserInput` to emit a new value, your query will resubscribe to `searchAsync` which will attempt to call `getDataFunc` again.

Comment: Catch is the right approach here; as otherwise noted, part of the "contract" is that an exception terminates the stream. Catching that exception (and doing something such that the exception does not propagate to the subscriber) allows you to handle errors in a slightly-more-robust manner.